# Const parameter passing: invalid conversion

Tags: c++, qt, constants

I am refactoring a bit of my Qt-cpp code and want to ensure that some QWidgets, gotten from public functions, are const (not alterable).

```
// class Tabbar:
const Tab* activeTab(){
    return this->activeTab;  // do I need a const here?
}

// class Tabwidget (Tabbar with stacked widget):
void TabWidget::setTabWidget(const Tab2* t,
                             QWidget *w, bool switchToTab)
{
    QWidget* oldWidget = tabWidgets_.take(t);    // <-- error
    if (oldWidget){
        stackedWidget_->removeWidget(oldWidget);
        delete oldWidget;
    }

    tabWidgets_.insert(t,w);                     // <-- error
    stackedWidget_->addWidget(w);
    // ...
}
```

The error is:

```
invalid conversion from "const Tab*" to "Tab*" [-fpermissive]
```

The documentation says on .take-mouseover:

```
T QHash::take(const Key &key)
```

...and I am passing a const Tab* as key, so I do not understand the message.
The header declaration is

```
void setTabWidget(const Tab *t, QWidget* w, bool switchToTab = false);
```

Also I am wondering if the `Tab` that I pass to `setTabWidget` needs to be const always.

Comment: Well, `t` is a pointer and `QHash::take` expects a reference, so something's gotta be wrong.

Comment: If I remove the "const" in the method declaration, it works. So there is no problem with passing a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

The method expects a reference and you're passing it a pointer. Just dereference the pointer.

```
QWidget* oldWidget = tabWidgets_.take(*t);
```

This is assuming of course that Tab is compatible with Key

Comment: Please explain why it compiles if I remove the `const`. It is still a pointer, then. Why would I need to dereference the `const Tab*`, when I don't need for the `Tab*`?

Comment: How is tabWidgets_ declared?

Comment: QHash<Tab*, QWidget*> tabWidgets_;    ... well that must be it. Why haven't I looked there before.

Comment: Yes, that's it. QHash only takes Tab* but not const Tab*.

Answer (score 0):

Once u delcare something as `const` you can't change it no metter what. Also if you define something in your class as const you have to use it as const whole program that means that you can't change it no matter what.[Reading this](http://duramecho.com/ComputerInformation/WhyHowCppConst.html) will help you out to understand concept of `const` how to use it and when to use it.

Comment: I know that. But where do I change the Tab?

QHash::take does not change it. It does remove a pointer to this Tab from the hash. Same for ::insert. The Tab is not modified, or am I missing something?

Comment: `QWidget* oldWidget = tabWidgets_.take(*t);`Just like guy from above said, just derefrence the pointer